# How to load multiple languages for gameplay3d?

Tags: game-engine, gameplay3d

How to load multiple languages for `gameplay3d`? I want to join other countries to support the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much about this engine, it seems that you can create your own ASCII fonts, and thus render those easily.

What you could do is create a simple multi-language system yourself with each language having a `gameplay::Font` object of its own.

See here for some more information on how to use this object: https://github.com/blackberry/GamePlay/wiki/Text-and-Fonts

of the `gameplay3d` forum if you haven't already tried it: http://www.gameplay3d.org/forums/

A basic multi-language system could be something like the following pseudo-code:

```
class LanguageManager
{
    private Language _currentLanguage = Language.enUS;
    private gameplay::Font[] _fonts;
    private gameplay::Font _currentFont;

    public void SetCurrentLanguage(Language l)
    {
        this._currentLanguage = l;
        this._currentFont = this.GetFontFromCurrentLanguage();
    }

    public void RenderString(string key, int x, int y, etc....)
    {
        string s = this.GetTextFromKey(key);

        this._currentFont.drawText(.....);
    }

    private GetFontFromCurrentLanguage()
    {
        etc...
    }

    private GetTextFromKey(string key)
    {
        // get the text from a the resource file
    }
}
```

You can store all of the language translations in a simple file with the following format and get the value from the above `LanguageManager.GetTextFromKey` method:

```
GameText.txt
[language]
key value

for instance
[enUS]
options Options
exit Exit

[zhCN]
options 选择
exit 离开
```